# Finding area with change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

What's the area under the curve $r=1+\sin \theta \,$?  I know I need a double integral and change of variables, but that's all I know from the question.

Comment: What does it mean *under* the curve? Enclosed by the curve and what else? For which range of $\theta$?

Comment: inside the curve. that's all the questions provides me

Comment: I suppose it's $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, as that gives us a closed curve.

Comment: Inside the curve and under the curve are different things.

Comment: Is there a particular method that you have to use for your class? I mean, you do not have to use a double integral...

Comment: gotta use double integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do, if you mean the area enclosed by the curve for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$. Not sure how to do this with a change of variable, I'm pretty sure that this is the easiest that this is going to get.

Let $D:=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2:r\leq1+\sin\theta\}$, then the area that we are interested in is given by the area integral over $D$.

Computing the area integral, we have

\begin{align}
\int_D dA&=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{1+\sin\theta}drr\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\left(1+\sin\theta\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\left(1+2\sin\theta+\sin^2\theta\right)\\
&=\pi+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\sin^2\theta\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\pi
\end{align}